# On Google Drive SDK, how to update a file with an empty content [CONFIRMED BUG]

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a file, and when I want to update it with an empty content, the API returns a successful request but doesn't update the content.

Request:

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/xxxxxxxxxx?uploadType=media
Content-Length = 0
Content-Type = binary/octet-stream
Authorization = Bearer xxxxx
```

The response code is 200 but the file is not updated.

I also tried with the uploadType=resumable and I have the same issue.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

@Martin I think Google does not allow you to override files in the drive, instead they update the timestamp and that way, you can have two files with the same name. The only update you can do I think is updating the metadata of the file. I might be wrong but haven't really played with updating a file with empty content. Also, are you using the API clients, because I believe they help you with most of the heavy lifting.

Comment: They do allow update (it's documented in the SDK), and it works if your update contains at least one byte. So I guess it's a bug (or I'm missing something). I don't use the API Client since it's an alpha version on iOS and I prefer to know exactly what happens under the hood :)

Comment: Confirmed. The content needs to be at least 1 byte in order to make the file change. I tried with `PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/xxxxxxxxxx?uploadType=multipart` to update both description and content of the file (blank content) in one request. The description did update but the content remained the same.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but we managed to reproduce the bug and work on a fix that will be live in the next 1-2 weeks.